# DBContext and AsNoTracking while running multiple Async/Await calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to add "AsNoTracking" to some of my DB calls, but I keep running into problems.

I have the following code:

```
    public class MyRepository
{
    private readonly CustomsDataContext _context;

    public AggregatedCustomsDataRepository(CustomsDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<AggregatedCustomsDataRow>> GetAggrigatedDataRowsCompanyNumber(string companyNumber, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        return await _context.AggrigatedDataRows
            .Where(x => x.companyNumber == companyNumber && 
                        fromDate <= x.FromDate && toDate >= x.ToDate)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<AggregatedCustomsDataRow>> GetAggregatedCustomsDataForPeriod(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        return await _context.AggrigatedDataRows
            .Where(x => fromDate <= x.FromDate && toDate >= x.ToDate)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<AggregatedCustomsDataRow>> GetAggrigatedDataRowsLastYear()
    {
        var periodFrom = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-12);
        var periodTo = DateTime.UtcNow;

        return await _context.AggrigatedDataRows
            .Where(x => x.FromDate >= periodFrom && x.ToDate <= periodTo)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
    }   
}

public MyController
{
    MyRepository _repo;
    MyOtherRepository _otherRepo;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<OutgoingDataRow>> DoWork(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var allData = _repo.GetAggregatedCustomsDataForPeriod(fromDate, toDate);
        var allDataCompanyA = _repo.GetAggrigatedDataRowsCompanyNumber("CompA", fromDate, toDate);
        var allDataCompanyB = _repo.GetAggrigatedDataRowsCompanyNumber("CompB",fromDate, toDate);
        var allDataLastYear = _repo.GetAggrigatedDataRowsLastYear();

        Task.WaitAll(allData, allDataCompanyA, allDataCompanyB);

        return (await _otherRepo.GetAllProductTypes()).Select(ProductType) =>
        {
            var tempA = allData.Result.Where(x=>x.ProductType.Code = ProductType.Code)
            var tempB = allDataCompanyA.Result.Where(x=>x.ProductType.Code = ProductType.Code)
            var tempC = allDataCompanyB.Result.Where(x=>x.ProductType.Code = ProductType.Code)
            var tempD = allDataLastYear.Result.Where(x=>x.ProductType.Code = ProductType.Code)

            // Use data from all tasks to build return object
            return new OutgoingDataRow
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove AsNoTracking, the code works fine, but if I add them I get a few errors which does not make much sense to me.

In one function I get:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

and in an other I get:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedConnecting' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds'.'

I have tried setting MultipleActiveResultSets=True but it does not make a difference.

I have tried using a new DbContext for each DB call, but I cant fully understand if that is a good idea or not.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can't run multiple queries against a single DbContext at the same time, it is not a thread safe object.

Comment: Ok, so all Task.WaitAll(dbTaskA, dbTaskB ...) is potentially unsafe? So only one active awaitable db call at any single time? Can I do multiple if they are to different unrelated tables?

Comment: You can only have one operation per `DbContext` instance running at a time. It doesn't matter which tables you are accessing. So here you would need to `await` each one individually.

Comment: Why did it work when I did not have the AsNoTracking there? Did it work just by chance?

Comment: Most likely yes.

Comment: I find it very strange it ever worked. Usually the `DbContext` will throw an exception when there are multiple simultaneous `async` operations. Maybe they were very fast and not actually overlapping?

Comment: Does adding no tracking make it slower? Without it, the program works 100% of the time (multiple months in production) on all tested machines, but when we add no tracking it fails 100% of the time on the 4 machines we have tested on. Making sure there was no multiple calls to the database fixed the issue, but I still find it strange that it worked so consistently by chance before.